# Trouble understanding Linear transformation question

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble figuring out how to solve a question

It is , consider a linear transformation $T: P_2(t) \to P_2(t)$ given by $T(p(t))=(t-1)\frac{dP}{dt}(t)$

What can we say about this, does here exist a $p \in P$ such that $t(p)=p$ or $t(p)=3p$ for example?

What I am thinking; well I think I could plug in values and find it but that wouldn't really satisfy me, I am thinking I can maybe using something like eigenvalues or diagolization somehow? But I am also confused on the notation, for example

say I want to consider $P=t^2+t+1$, then would $T(t^2+t+1)=(t-1)\frac{dP}{dt}(t)$ or would it be say $T(t^2+t+1)=(t^2+t+1-1)\frac{dP}{dt}t^2+t+1$

I know there is a theorem in my book along the lines of Consider a linear operator $T:V \to V$ then T is said to be diagonalizble if it can be represented by a diagonal matrix D: thus T is diagonlizble if and only if there exists a basis $B=\{u_1,..,u_n\}$ of V for which  $T(u_1)=k_1u_u1...T(u_n)=k_nu_n$ and if so $D=\{k_1,...,k_n\}$ Maybe this can help but im not sure how I could use it?

Update: I formed the matrix $$M= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I did characteristic polynomial and solved for $\lambda(\lambda -2)(\lambda+1)$

I could solve for the eigen vectors , and form a diagonal matrix but, will this help?

Update:

what I did was try to make $D=Q^{-1}AQ$

where $$D=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

and $$Q=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

How does this look? Any suggestions on the last part of the question?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $P_2(t)$ is the polynomials in $t$ with real coefficients and degree less than or equal to two.

You can easily find the polynomials that satisfy $T(p)=p$ by realizing that this is a differential equation. The equation is

$$p=(t-1)\frac{dp}{dt}$$

This is separable, so

$$\frac{dp}p=\frac{dt}{t-1}$$

which has the solution

$$p=c(t-1)$$

The equation was linear, so we are not surprised that the solution is an arbitrary constant times a certain function. We now know that $t-1$ is an eigenvector of your transformation $T$ with eigenvalue $1$.

We can find all the eigenvectors by solving $T(p)=kp$; i.e.

$$kp=(t-1)\frac{dp}{dt}$$

This is again separable and has the solution

$$p=c(t-1)^k$$

Since we are limited to polynomials of degree at most two, this gives us $k=0,1,2$. As expected, we get three eigenvalues for our three dimensional vector space.

This gives us a diagonalized matrix for our transformation $T$:

$$D=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

under the basis $(t-1)^0,\ (t-1)^1,\ (t-1)^2$; i.e. under the basis $1,\ t-1,\ t^2-2t+1$, which are the (non-normalized) eigenvectors of $T$. You already have the matrix for $T$ for the standard basis $1,\ t,\ t^2$ (though I got a different one: see the end of this answer). You should now easily be able to find the matrix $Q$ for the relevant change of basis.

Note that there is no non-zero vector $p$ such that $T(p)=3p$, at least not in your given vector space, since $3$ is not an eigenvalue here.

Also note that under the basis $1,\ t,\ t^2$ I get this matrix for $T$:

$$M=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 &-1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-2 \\
  0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and that matrix does have the eigenvalues $0,\ 1,\ 2$. I get the transition matrix

$$Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 &-2 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and it all seems to work out. I do get $D=Q^{-1}MQ$.

Comment: Hi, I beleive I have the Q above

Comment: @PersonaA: Since you calculated the characteristic polynomial as $\lambda(\lambda -2)(\lambda+1)$, you got the eigenvalues $0,\ -1,\ 2$, whereas I got $0,\ 1,\ 2$. One of us is wrong.

Comment: Ah, well im sure that would be me. I will look over it, thanks

Comment: Hm I am not sure anymore, i still get what I originally did, i wonder where it is going wrong

Comment: Look at the end of my answer. I got a different matrix $M$ for the transformation $T$ than you did. I used the basis $1,t,t^2$, which is standard, and the top row stands for $1$ and the bottom row for $t^2$. You may be confused in your basis or for converting the transformation to a matrix with that basis. Your $M$ is upside-down compared to mine.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but do you know where I could have gone wrong in the matrix? I thought the columns form the basis matrix

Comment: @PersonaA: $T(t^2)=2t^2-2t$, so the *third* column (representing $t^2$) has the entry $2$ in the row that represents $t^2$. Since the third *column* represents $t^2$ so should the third $row$, but you put the $2$ in the *first* row. I.e. in the columns you have $1,t,t^2$ but in the rows you tried to have $t^2,t,1$; the wrong order. The rows and columns must match in their order. I put the rows in the right order, so my basis is consistently $1,t,t^2$. Your matrix $M$ is upside-down due to the mismatch of orders. Clear?

Comment: @PersonaA Yes, thankyou for your time

Answer (score 0):

For $P = t^2 + t + 1$, 
\begin{align}
T(P) 
&= (t-1) \times \frac{dP}{dt} \\
&= (t-1) \times (2t+1) \\
&= (2t^2-2t) + (t - 1)\\
&= 2t^2-t - 1
\end{align}

A few more cases:

For $P = 0$, $T(P) = 0$.

For $P = 1$, $T(P) = 0$.

For $P = t$, $T(P) = t-1$.

For $P = t^2$, $T(P) = (t-1)\times 2t = 2t^2 - 2t$.

Does this begin to make sense?

Now you can do something like say, "What if $P = at^2 + bt + c$? What would $T(P)$ comes out to, in terms of $a,b,c$? It'd be some polynomial...is there any choice of $a,b,c$ that would make it come out to exactly the original polynomial? Or 3 times the original polynomial?"

Alternatively, you could (from the things I've given you) write down thee matrix of the transformation with respect to the basis $1, t, t^2$, and then look for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of that matrix, which might be more familiar to you.

Comment: And I am wondering, why does the (t-1) stay as t-1? and not become t+t^2 for example?  In other words, I am saying if P(t) is the poly nomial then t=t^2+t+1 when we do that case no?

Comment: You pick a basis -- I recommend $1, t, t^2$ -- and compute $T$ applied to each element. You write the result in terms of the basis. For instance $T(t^2) = 2t^2 - 2$. That's $-2 \times 1 + 0 \times t + 2 \times t^2$, so the coefficients, in that basis, are $-2, 0, 1$. Do this for the first basis element ($P = 1$), and put the coefficients into the first column of a $3 \times 3 $ matrix. Do it for the second basis element, and put the coeffs into the second column. Do it for the third col...I already did it for you! .. and put these in the 3rd col. That's your $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: Okay, but I am just confused because it is T(p(t))=(t-1)(dp/dt(t)), so then isnt T(p(t^2+t+1))=(t^2+t+1-1)(dp/dt(t^2+t+1))?

Comment: $dP/dt$ denotes the derivative of $P$ with respect to $t$; in your case, that's $2t + 1$. The definition of $T$ doesn't say that $T(t) = (t-1) dP/dt$...it's says that $T(P) = (t-1) dP/dt$, i.e, to transform a polynomial $P$, you take its derivative to get a new polynomial $Q$, and multiply $Q$ by the polynomial $(t-1)$ to get the final result.

Comment: Okay thanks, I added some of my work to the question, does it look okay?

Comment: That looks good. Those should be the columns of your matrix, so your matrix looks like $\begin{bmatrix}2 & * & * \\ -2 & * & * \\0 & * & *  \end{bmatrix}$. You go ahead and fill in the rest, and then try to find its eignvalues. Hint: one of them is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think your notation is a little cluttered. So, let's pick a generic $p(t) \in P_2(t)$. Let's write $p(t) = at^2 + bt + c$.

Thus, $\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}p(t) = \frac{d}{dt}[at^2 + bt + c] = 2at + b$.

Now, if we want to look at $T(p(t))$, we just multiply $\frac{dp}{dt}$ by $t - 1$:

$$T(p(t)) = (t - 1)\frac{dp}{dt} = (t - 1)(2at + b) = 2at^2 + (b - 2a)t - b.$$

So, let's represent our polynomial $p(t) = at^2 + bt + c$ as the vector $\vec{p} = (a, b, c)$. Thus, we can see that $\vec{p} = (a, b, c) \overset{T}{\longrightarrow} \vec{T(p)} = (2a, b - 2a, -b)$.

Using the basis $\{t^2, t, 1\}$ of $P_2(t)$, we can see that

\begin{align*}
t^2 \cong (1, 0, 0) &\overset{T}{\to} (2,-2,0) \cong (t - 1)\frac{d}{dt}[t^2]\\
t \cong (0, 1, 0) &\overset{T}{\to} (0, 1 ,-1)\cong (t - 1)\frac{d}{dt}[t] \\
1 \cong (0, 0 ,1) &\overset{T}{\to} (0, 0, 0) \cong (t - 1)\frac{d}{dt}[1].
\end{align*}

This is the kind of work that would help you find a matrix representation of the transformation $T$.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I am also confused on how to know that it always stays t-1, i thought t depends on what the polynomial is, but from the answers it seems it does not?

Comment: No, we always use $(t - 1)$. The map $T$ explicitly says that we take $(t - 1)$ and multiply that by the derivative of $p$, regardless of what the polynomial $p$ is.

Comment: I see, and when you do t^2, why do you have (2,-1,0) instead of (2,-2,0)?

Comment: @PersonaA I should have $(2, -2, 0)$, that's just me making mistakes. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Thanks, I put an update onto my question

Answer (score 0):

The two questions you ask are: Is there a $p$ such that $Tp=p$, and is there a $p$ such that $Tp=3p$?

The polynomials in question are given by $p(t):=at^2+bt +c$, and the polynomial $Tp$ is then given by $Tp(t)=2at^2+(b-2a)t-b$. It follows that the effect of $T$ on the coefficient vector $(a,b,c)$ of $p$ has the form
$$T:\quad(a,b,c)\mapsto(2a,b-2a,-b)\ .$$
If we want $Tp=p$ then the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ have to satisfy
$$a=2a,\quad b=b-2a,\quad c=-b\ .\tag{1}$$
It is easy to see that the solutions to $(1)$ are
$$(a,b,c):=(0,b,-b)\qquad (b\in{\mathbb R})\ ,$$
which means that these are the polynomials $p(t)=b(t-1)$ with arbitrary $b\in{\mathbb R}$.

If we want $Tp=3p$ then the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ have to satisfy
$$3a=2a,\quad 3b=b-2a,\quad 3c=-b\ .\tag{2}$$
These three equations in turn enforce $a=0$, $b=0$, $c=0$. Therefore the polynomial $p(t)\equiv0$ is the sole polynomial in $P_2$ (the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq2$)  with $Tp=3p$.